# How to produce two column that will not repeat the data

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi can I ask some help how can I produce this lat, lng ?

I tried this code but it keeps repeating the lat,lng values

```
SELECT h.*, d.* from
  stdtbl h 
  inner 
     join (
        select std_dtl_id,lat,lng, count(*) total 
       from stdtbl_detail group by std_dtl_id
     ) d

  on h.id = d.std_dtl_id
   inner join stdtbl_detail dt on h.id = dt.std_dtl_id
  where
  h.loginid = '1' AND  h.stdid='013777'
```

How can I output like this

```
id          stdid                 loginid                 std_dtl_id         lat                       lng                      total

372         013777                 1                      372                51.507407                 -0.127753                   4

372         013777                 1                      372                51.507384                 -0.127636                    4             

372         013777                 1                      372                51.507332                -0.127839                     4

372         013777                 1                      372                51.507304                 -0.127703                    4


373         013777                 1                      373               40.764442                  -73.923469                   4

373         013777                 1                      373               40.764416                   -73.923329                 4

373         013777                 1                      373               40.764346                   -73.923557                 4

373         013777                 1                      373                40.764299                   -73.923432                 4
```

here is the demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6a86/8

Thank you in advance.

Comment: that output is also repeating the values?

Comment: try using `distinct`

Comment: nevermind, no it doesnt.

Comment: what is your expected output can you explain. ?

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande, I posted the ouput i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you ask:

```
  select h.*, d.*, f.total 
    from stdtbl h
      inner join stdtbl_detail d   
        on h.id = d.std_dtl_id
      inner join 
        (select std_dtl_id, count(*) total from stdtbl_detail group by std_dtl_id) f
          on f.std_dtl_id = h.id
```

And i have updated your fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6a86/25

Comment: well, `group by` is not needed

Comment: @pala_ yeah,I think this is what i want :)

Answer (score 1):

With analytics, this would be easy. Without, it's still not terribly difficult. First, just do a join of the two tables to get most of your desired output.

```
SELECT  s.id, s.stdid, s.loginid, d.lat, d.lng
from    stdtbl s
join    stdtbl_detail d
    on  d.std_dtl_id = s.id
where   s.loginid = '1'
    AND s.stdid   = '013777';
```

This gets you what you want less the `total` field at the end. To get that, just generate a one-row-per-id result and join to that:

```
SELECT  s.id, s.stdid, s.loginid, d.lat, d.lng, a.total
from    stdtbl s
join    stdtbl_detail d
    on  d.std_dtl_id = s.id
join(
    select  std_dtl_id, count(*) total 
    from    stdtbl_detail
    group by std_dtl_id
) a
    on  a.std_dtl_id = d.std_dtl_id
where   s.loginid = '1'
    AND s.stdid   = '013777';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6a86/31/0